# Shortest way to get a value from a dictionary or a default if the key is not present

Tags: python, dictionary

I am just curious if

```
p = 'padding' in ui and ui['padding'] or 0
```

is the shortest way (or if there is an even shorter way) of writing

```
if 'padding' in ui:
   p = ui['padding']
else:
   p = 0
```

in Python.

Comment: `p = ui['padding'] if 'padding' in ui else 0`

Comment: It's not even a good way. If `ui['padding']` does exist but equals something like `""` or `[]`, `p` will be set to 0, not the value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `ui` is a dictionary, you can even simplify that with the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method, like this

```
p = ui.get('padding', 0)
```

Here, if the key `padding` exists in the dictionary, then the value corresponding to that will be returned. Otherwise, the default value passed as the second parameter will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's not shorter because of the `import` line but you can also change `ui` to be a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

ui = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```

Then the way you'd write what you originally had would simply be:

```
ui['padding']
```

Not the shortest overall due to the setup, but once it's set up it's the shortest access to write out.

Comment: This has one side-effect. This will create the key `padding`, if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
p = ui['padding'] if 'padding' in ui else 0
```

This is called a [ternary expression.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Comment: FYI the OP seems to be using the ["and-or trick"](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html) unleashed upon us by Dive Into Python. It's long been one of the most controversial parts of that tutorial since it encourages the use of such an implicit and unreadable piece of Python.

Comment: Why is it that we get so many questions about Dive Into Python The Hard Way Academy, but none about the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial)? Mysteries...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, it's in the language, it survived to 3x, sometimes it is a concise And readable way to express an idea.

Comment: @wwii I've used it before, but more as `if function_call() and another_function()` where `function_call()` returns a boolean indicating success and `another_function()` depends on `function_call()`

Comment: @wwii I don't have any problem with the way any of the involved language constructs behave, but I do not concede that stringing them together in this way is readable or explicit.

Comment: @wwii To clarify my original comment was in reference to trying to create a ternary expression using `and` and `or` (because they happen to return one of the compared values rather than a boolean). I have no problem with the `x if cond else y` way of writing it.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - I definitely misread your original comment.